# How to get the HDFS file data between 2 dates only in nifi workflow?

Tags: apache-nifi

I have some files stored in HDFS server.Now I want to fetch the files of one week only.Meanwhile while fetching the data I have to make one regEx where I have to fetch only one week data only.
Example:We have data on server like.

```
dt=2019-12-25
dt=2019-12-26
dt=2019-12-27
dt=2019-12-28
dt=2019-12-29
dt=2019-12-30
dt=2019-12-31
```

The rest of data I have to delete.

Comment: to get one week older files, you can use `Maximum File Age` property of `ListHDFS/GetHDFS` processor to set value to 7 day. But this property does not support Nifi expression language.

Comment: Workaround for automation -  after getting all the files using `ListHDFS`  try using `hdfs.lastModified` attribute and then `UpdateAttribute` to derive days and `RouteOnAttribute` to to route required files. So flow should be like `ListHDFS => UpdateAttribute (calculate days) => RouteOnAttribute`

Comment: refer this - [Apache NiFi template which calculates the difference between two dates and converts to nanoseconds](https://gist.github.com/alopresto/87a3d52f69c3695a13d824633975716b)




[how to derive yesterday 's date](https://community.cloudera.com/t5/Support-Questions/nifi-how-to-derive-yesterday-s-date-like-09-12-2016-11-59-59/td-p/163732)